# The show message statements are not printing even when the criteria is met, I am a bit stuck on this one

Tags: python, printing

```
if event.direction == "down":
      sense.show_message("D1")
      number = random.randint(1,6)
      if number == 1:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      elif number == 2:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      elif number == 3:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      elif number == 4:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      elif number == 5:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      else:
        number == 6
        sense.set_pixels(images[number % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      sense.show_message("D2")
      time.sleep(0.5)
      
      number2 = random.randint(1,6)
      if number2 == 1:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      if number2 == 2:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      if number2 == 3:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      if number2 == 4:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      if number2 == 5:
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      else:
        number2 == 6
        sense.set_pixels(images[number2 % len(images)]())
        time.sleep(.75)
      sense.show_message("C")
      mathnum = number
      mathnum2 = number2
      if mathnum == mathnum2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sense.show_message("Thats a double!")
      if mathnum + mathnum == 7:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sense.show_message("Thats a seven!")
      if mathnum + mathnum2 == 11:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sense.show_message("Thats an eleven!")
      else:
        continue
```

The show message statements dont print when the criteria is met, when mathnum is 3 and mathnum2 is 4 it should print "thats a seven" but it doesnt. Im not sure what the issue is here there is a list where it gets the information on how to print out a certain number dice face because its an LED face

Comment: `if mathnum + mathnum == 7:` That statement can _never_ be true, because you can't add an integer to itself and get an odd result.  Perhaps you meant to add mathnum and mathnum2?

Comment: ah yeah i see that now, im sure it isnt working with the eleven one tho either, it will print eleven while the numbers clearly dont add up to eleven... really confusing

Comment: The eleven should work, as far as I can see.

Comment: thanks alot anyway ill keep at it! hope i can get good enough to help others here i do appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah just had one where number was 6 and number2 was 3 and it said "thats a seven" i dont understand :/